# problem with kile installation in fedora 13 + texlive

Tags: kile, texlive, installing

I recently started using fedora with kde and I want to install kile. But, the version of TeX Live in the official repositories is TeX Live 2007 and I want a more complete and recent version. I tried adding the repository for fedora 13 found [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/TeXLive) but it does not work says it is not an rpm package.
Has anyone with fedora 13 been able to install kile 2.1 beta 4 with a version of texlive 2009 or 2010?

When I installed kile from the official repositories it also installed texlive2007 as a dependency, and I can not install kile compiling configured to use texlive 2009.

Comment: The link you gave isn't a repository, but a page with links to the repositories for various fedora versions. Did you try those links, or did you somehow try to use the link you gave as though it was the repository?

Comment: I use the link to my version of fedora 13 /// rpm -i http://jnovy.fedorapeople.org/texlive/texlive-f13-release-2009-0.3.fc12.noarch.rpm  /// but i can´t installed the repositorie thanks for answering

Comment: This isn't a question about LaTeX or friends, but about installing texlive. Perhaps move it to super user?

Comment: @Seamus: I disagree. 1) TeX Live is obviously in the extension of 'LaTeX and friends' and installation *is* part of using the software. 2) If we are going to allow questions about [related applications](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/139/are-questions-about-related-applications-ok) and the like, we ought to allow "how do I install a given TeX distribution?" 3) If and when we leave beta, if we chase them to super user, those folks might well chase them back.

Comment: Similar problem on ubuntu, solved by building kile from source.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
wget http://jnovy.fedorapeople.org/texlive/texlive-f13-release-2009-0.3.fc12.noarch.rpm
```

Then

```
sudo rpm -Uvh texlive-f13-release-2009-0.3.fc12.noarch.rpm
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually, you got couple suggestions which I find rather problematic. I am not using Fedora but I am an avid OpenBSD user and even though our OpenBSD TeXLive porter and port maintainer is Edd Barret I feel I can say something competently about TeX package on Unix and Unix like systems.

There is a good reason why official repository has 2007 TeXLive version. TeXLive is non-trivial to port and many, many other packages depend on that specific version of TeXLive. Fedora project might lack resources to update the package or maybe they found some more serious dependency related issues. Manually installing newer version of TeXLive can easily brake your Fedora installation and Yum in packaging system in particular. I would suggest that you run the newest version of TeXLive from a CD or to install it on a USB stick. You can find instructions how to do this in section 4.1 and 4.2 of [official TeXLive documenation](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-40001.2)

There are some more complicated solutions than the one above. For example you could install the newest version of TeXLive in chroot environment (do you know what I am talking about). Or you could even port TeXLive 2011 to Fedora but that would be a huge project.

Comment: In case of Fedora there is no "good reason why official repository has 2007 TeXLive version". The only reason is missing man power. Updating the repros is (as you already have mentioned) a lot of work, and since no-one is willing to do this, there are lots of Fedora people who vote for removing TL from the Fedora repros since it can be easily installed using the official TL installer. And how can "Manually installing newer version of TeXLive easily brake your Fedora installation"? IMHO this is simply not true since TL will be installed in a separate directory, there is absolutely no risk.

Comment: Missing man power is a very good reason for TeXLive not to be updated. Unlike OS X and Windows, which install entire binaries with all necessary libraries in a container, Linux distros at least the main one just like OpenBSD use the concept of the share libraries and compile packages against the specific kernel and userland version. That is why you do have only one version of libc library on your Linux machine unlike on Windows and OS X where you might have 2000 copies. Now use your HO and figure out what happens if you have two conflicting version of libc libraries.

Comment: As already said, the whole TL will be installed into a separate directory (without own shared libraries). The rest of the system will not be touched. (If you want to have TeXlive within your PATH, you'll have to edit your profile yourself.) There is absolutely no way how this could break Fedora and/or yum. And the installation is even recommended by Fedora people. Instead of spreading FUD you should try it out and take a look at yourself.

Comment: Now look at my original post that you voted down and in particular sentence:"For example you could install the newest version of TeXLive in chroot environment". If the OP knew about it and other options he would not be asking question to begin with. As of me I can very well install just a parts of new TL tree, hash the database and sleep peacefully with working installation of TL. By the way the default TL port on OpenBSD is 2010 and 2011 is already in current ports tree. So much about OpenBSD not being usable as the desktop OS.