# error when trying to compile .tex files: File `pgfpages.sty' not found. \RequirePackage

Tags: packages, texlive, installing, linux

Compiling this file worked well under Linux Mint 17.2, but since I upgraded to Mint 18, I get this error. I tried installing pgfpages with tlmgr, but the package isn't present in repositories. I get the same problem with the tikz-package but I read I shouldn't install that manually but update texlive instead. Did that, error persists.

dpkg --get-selections | grep tex tells me that 
texlive, tex-common, texlive-base, texlive-binaries, texlive-fonts-recommended, texlive-latex-base, texlive-latex-recommended
are installed.

I don't understand what's going on. Also, my /home//texmf/tex/latex only contains a directory named xargs which only contains one file, is that normal? I tried reinstalling texlive but to no effect. Any idea what I could do?

Comment: AFAIK `pgfpages` should indeed be in `texlive-latex-recommended`. However: Install [`texlive-full`](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/texlive-full) to avoid such problems or install [Vanilla TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive).

Comment: @Schweinebacke Do you want to write up an answer?

Comment: @TeXnician Don't know, what I should answer. `pdfpages.sty` should be in `texlive-latex-recommended`. Medusa told us, that `texlive-latex-recommended` was already installed. So installation of `texlive-full` or Vanilla TeX Live is only an idea but not a proofed solution. And I would expect, that we already have similar questions with answers, that recommend installation of `texlive-full` or Vanilla TeX Live. I will try …

Comment: I've asked a more general version of this question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/407258/86 with the aim of broadening the underlying idea of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Vanilla TeX Live](http://www.tug.org/texlive) installer by default installs a full TeX Live with (almost) all packages available for the current TeX Live. So after a default installation of Vanilla TeX Live missing packages will be restricted to such packages, that are not available as TeX Live package and have to be installed manually (or maybe from another repository).

Linux distributions usually split TeX Live in several packages. Most distributions provide online or offline tools to search for the package, that provides a wanted package. But most Linux distributions also provide a package [`texlive-full`](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/texlive-full) (or similar named package) that installs all TeX Live packages. If you want avoid most missing package problems, you should install this package.

If your Linux distribution provides the current main release of TeX Live with `tlmgr` you could also use the `tlmgr` user mode to install a package in the user tree. See `tlmgr help` for more information. But note, if the TeX Live of your Linux distribution is to old, you cannot use `tlmgr` to install or update packages from the TeX Live main repository. Note also, some packages cannot be installed in user mode. And if you have installed a package once in user mode, you also have to update it in user mode as long as it is in the used user tree (even after installation of a newer TeX Live main release).

See also:

- [LaTeX not finding .sty files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329847/latex-not-finding-sty-files)
- [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu)
- [Best way to install packages for TeXLive in Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28528/best-way-to-install-packages-for-texlive-in-ubuntu)
- [Determine full list of installed LaTeX packages in Ubuntu](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125058/determine-full-list-of-installed-latex-packages-in-ubuntu)
- [What is the difference between install texlive through iso image and through apt-get in Ubuntu?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41026/what-is-the-difference-between-install-texlive-through-iso-image-and-through-apt)
- [tlmgr cannot setup TLPDB](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137428/tlmgr-cannot-setup-tlpdb)
- [How to install “vanilla” TeXLive on Fedora?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301126/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-fedora)

…