# How do I find out which Linux package contains which (La)TeX package?

Tags: packages, installing, linux, big-list

I'm using (La)TeX as installed by my Linux/Unix distribution.  I've come across a package that I don't have installed.  How do I find out which Linux/Unix package contains that (La)TeX package?

Notes:

1. This is a *public service* question, please take that into account when answering.  More than ever, good answers should be detailed.
2. If the distribution has an "install everything" package, that's worth mentioning.  But some people want to only install what they need so please still answer the question as asked.
3. Please specify the flavour of Linux/Unix in your answer.

---

*I don't think we have a question that covers this, but obviously if someone finds it then we'll delete this one.*

Comment: This is more or less a Linux question: "How to find out which Linux package contains which file?". This is off-topic here, isn't it?

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Well it's borderline. It also depends quite a bit on the Linux distribution. I agree that it is actually better suited for https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've added tag [`big-list`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tags/big-list/info). Hope this was correct.

Comment: @MartinScharrer there is a LaTeX specific part of how to find what files are provided by a package and where in the texmf-dist tree they are located.

Comment: Technically, all questions should be public service questions - that's the entire purpose of Stack Exchange ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit My meaning was that this isn't a question that I'm asking because I want to know the answer *myself* but rather that I felt it a question that ought to be asked-and-answered here.

Comment: @LoopSpace: I got it. Again, FWIW that's actually perfectly commonplace and normal. Merry Christmas!

Comment: A very useful question indeed. Thanks @AndrewStacey for asking it. I wonder why some people are trying so hard to disqualify such and such question.

Answer (score 39):

Most Linux distributions provide a tool to find out which distribution package contains which file. Some distributions provide a website as well.

### Which file do I want?

- For `\usepackage{foo}` (LaTeX package), you need `foo.sty`.
- For `\documentclass{foo}` (LaTeX class), you need `foo.cls`.
- For `\input foo` (TeX macro file), you need `foo.tex`.
- For `\bibligraphystyle{foo}` (BibTeX style), you need `foo.bst`.
- For a font, it depends on the font's encoding. The easiest thing would be to look for the LaTeX package that makes the requisite declarations (`foo.sty`).

If you know which CTAN package you want, on [CTAN](http://ctan.org/), follow the “Sources” link and look at the file names there. Note that `.dtx` files are used to generate other files; often one of the generated file has the same name and the extension `.sty` (for LaTeX) or `.tex` (for other formats), but this is a habit, not a rule.

If you use a graphical package manager, check if it has an option to search a package by file name. If not, see below for command line methods.

### Debian, Ubuntu, Linux Mint, elementary OS...

On Debian-based distributions, the tool [`apt-file`](https://wiki.debian.org/apt-file) lets you search the package database by file name. First, install it if it is not installed already. You only need to do this once, and to run `apt-file update` after upgrading to a new release of the distribution.

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

Here's an example of looking for a given file and installing the package containing it. `$` represents a shell prompt.

```
$ apt-file search /foils.sty
foiltex: /usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/foiltex/foils.sty
$ sudo apt-get install foiltex
```

Some Debian derivatives may include the `apt-file` program but not the databases that it needs to function. If so you'll need to find another way. Chances are that the derivative hasn't changed the way the TeX packages are organized, so you can use the web to find out where it is in Debian or Ubuntu:

- [Debian: search the contents of packages](https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages#search_contents)
- [Ubuntu: search the contents of packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/#search_contents)

### Red Hat, CentOS, Fedora

Modern releases use `dnf`, which offers the following command:

```
dnf provides '*/foils.sty'
```

Older releases use `yum`, which has a similar command with a slightly different name:

```
yum whatprovides '*/foils.sty'
```

Note that both commands need a full path, not just the base name of the file. But you can use `*` to replace a part of the path that you don't know, thus `*/foils.sty` looks for a file called `foils.sty` located anywhere.

Once you've identified the package name, install it with `sudo dnf install …` or `sudo yum install …`.

### SuSE

See [Schweinebacke's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407258/how-do-i-find-out-which-linux-package-contains-which-latex-package/407264#407264). In a nutshell:

```
zypper search --provides --match-exact 'tex(foo.sty)'
sudo zypper install …
```

### Arch Linux

You can [search for packages by contents with pacman](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Search_for_a_package_that_contains_a_specific_file). First update the local database:

```
sudo pacman -Fy
```

(or `su -c 'pacman -Fy'` or using whatever method you prefer to run commands as root). Then, to search for a specific file name:

```
pacman -F /foo.sty
```

or `pkgfile foo.sty`.

Once you've identified the package name, install it with `pacman -S`.

### Gentoo

You can [search for the package providing a given file name with equery](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Equery#Finding_the_package_that_a_file_came_from_with_belongs_.28b.29).

```
equery belongs /foo.sty
```

### FreeBSD

Try searching for a port on [Porgle](http://www.secnetix.de/tools/porgle/porgle.py). Tick the “packing list” checkbox to search by file name.

### Where else can I look for help?

- Your distribution's documentation, of course!
- [Pacman Rosetta](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta#Querying_specific_packages): look for an equivalent of `apt-file search`
- [Rosetta Stone for Unix](http://bhami.com/rosetta.html): look for an equivalent of `apt-file`.
- [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange: How to find out which (not installed) package a file belongs to?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6311/how-to-find-out-which-not-installed-package-a-file-belongs-to/6314#6314)

Comment: Arch Linux does not have `sudo` by default.

Comment: I think Gentoo's `equery belongs` only works for files that actually exist on the system. Or perhaps only for installed packages. The point is, if you want to find which package you should install to obtain a file that you don't already have, `equery` isn't going to be much help.

Comment: On Gentoo Linux you look up the filename of the package like `siunitx.sty`with http://portagefilelist.de/ There was a tool `dev-tex/texmfind`, but we removed it in favour portagefilelist and its tools. equery will only work on installed files.

Comment: This is an amazing answer! Very useful.

Answer (score 20):

[image: Gotta love the hightech pig] [image: Ubuntu]

Debian and Debian-related Linux distributions have [`apt-file`](https://wiki.debian.org/apt-file) to find the Linux package that contains a file, e.g.:

```
apt-file update
apt-file search extarticle.cls
```

should result in

> ```
> texlive-latex-recommended: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/extsizes/extarticle.cls
> ```

Note, this method only shows files of already installed repositories.

To be able to use this file search, you still need to know a file related to a (La)TeX package. For LaTeX-classes this should always be the class name with appended file extension `.cls`. For LaTeX-packages you should add the extension `.sty`. But most simple way is to try to use the package and have a look into the `.log` file. (La)TeX tells you which file is does not find. This should also work for most other kind of files.

Comment: ooh a pig with candles! `:)`

Comment: @LoopSpace ??? How could you not? Why should you search for something you do not know? Or is your question: How can I find out, what packages are available for which purpose? This would be something completely different than I've understood from your question above. I'm very confused know. But, If this would be your question, I'd delete this answer.

Comment: @Schweinebacke ooh a hightech pig! `:)`

Comment: For a non-expert user, it's probably much simpler to just use the search tool at https://packages.ubuntu.com/ or https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages ("search the content of packages", [example](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=elsarticle.cls&mode=exactfilename&suite=artful&arch=any)).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Running `apt-file` isn't complicated, it is very, very easy. So IMHO "much simpler" is a little bit exaggerated. LaTeX users should also be able to run a console application. And users do not need to be online to use `apt-file`. And most online kiddies will also find the answer using Google, Bing …

Comment: @Schweinebacke What is the use case of doing this search offline? You need to have access to the internet anyway to install the package afterwards... In any case I agree, which method is easier is probably just a matter of personal preference.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Do you know Ubuntu/Debian on DVD or USB stick? Not everyone has everywhere good and free internet connection. And I'm not talking about Himalaya or Central Africa. I'm German and we have still villages in Black Forrest with very, very small bandwidth.

Answer (score 16):

[image: A duck was here]

For SuSE Linux it is a little bit more tricky, because searching in the file list of a package is only provided for already installed package.

`zypper search` provides searching for installed and not yet installed packages, that provides *capabilities*. But you have to know which capability you are searching. For TeX capabilities the packages contain provides information like `tex(article.cls)` or `tex(pgf.sty)` so you can do, e.g.:

```
zypper search --provides --match-exact 'tex(article.cls)'
```

to get:

> ```
> S | Name          | Summary                                | Type   
> --+---------------+----------------------------------------+--------
>   | texlive-latex | A TeX macro package that defines LaTeX | package
> ```

or

```
zypper search --provides --match-exact 'tex(pgf.sty)'
```

to get

> ```
>  S | Name        | Summary                                   | Type   
>  --+-------------+-------------------------------------------+--------
>    | texlive-pgf | Create PostScript and PDF graphics in TeX | package
> ```

You can also use wildcards, e.g.:

```
zypper search --provides 'tex(*article.cls)'
```

to get several packages with classes names `…article.cls`, e.g. `article.cls`, `extarticle.cls` etc.:

> ```
>  S | Name               | Summary                                      | Type   
>  --+--------------------+----------------------------------------------+--------
>    | texlive-afparticle | Typesetting articles for Archives of Foren-> | package
>    | texlive-bangtex    | Writing Bangla and Assamese with LaTeX       | package
>    | texlive-bxjscls    | Japanese document class collection for all-> | package
>    | texlive-elsarticle | Class for articles for submission to Elsev-> | package
>    | texlive-extsizes   | Extend the standard classes' size options    | package
>    | texlive-gzt        | Bundle of classes for "La Gazette des Math-> | package
>    | texlive-jsclasses  | Classes tailored for use with Japanese       | package
>    | texlive-latex      | A TeX macro package that defines LaTeX       | package
>    | texlive-luatexja   | Typeset Japanese with Lua(La)TeX             | package
>    | texlive-platex     | PLaTeX2e and miscellaneous macros for pTeX   | package
>    | texlive-skb        | Tools for a repository of long-living docu-> | package
>    | texlive-uplatex    | PLaTeX2e and miscellaneous macros for upTeX  | package
> ```

If you search for the package to install it, you can also install using the capability, e.g.,

```
sudo zypper install --dry-run 'tex(datatool.sty)'
```

will install package `texlive-datatool-2017.132.2.27svn41772-33.1.noarch`.

Comment: I really envy `zypper` over `dnf` (although I must say `dnf` is *way better* in Fedora 27). I always have fun with my OpenSUSE machine!

Comment: I don't recommend using the texlive packages from SuSE.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer As you can see in the output I don't use them myself (empty S column), but this wasn't the question. However they became much better over the years. BTW: I also do not use the texlive packages from debian/ubuntu. But I wouldn't say, that all these linux packages are useless or that I generally should warn about using them. I know users using them successfully.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: I didn't write that they are not usable successfully but are often outdated.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Not more than the texlive packages of other linux distributions. What is outdated? TeX Live installation from this week could be called outdated next week. But not all users need brand new packages. So TeX Live from this year often is enough. Currently [`texlive`](https://software.opensuse.org/package/texlive) for Tumbleweed is TeX Live 2017. Not an up-to-date TeX Live 2017 but TeX Live 2017. Sometimes the SuSE packages provide the older TeX Live, sometimes Debian, sometimes …

Answer (score 14):

[image: Fedora logo]

Here's the Fedora way. First, we can use `dnf list` and list all packages matching the string query:

```
$ dnf list texlive-*
Last metadata expiration check: 0:43:39 ago on Fri Dec 22 09:17:10 2017.
Installed Packages
texlive-algorithms.noarch                6:svn38085.0.1-36.fc27.5        @fedora
texlive-amsfonts.noarch                  6:svn29208.3.04-36.fc27.5       @fedora
texlive-amsmath.noarch                   6:svn41561-36.fc27.5            @fedora
texlive-attachfile.noarch                6:svn38830-36.fc27.5            @fedora
texlive-auto-pst-pdf.noarch              6:svn23723.0.6-36.fc27.5        @fedora
texlive-babel.noarch                     6:svn40706-36.fc27.5            @fedora
texlive-babelbib.noarch                  6:svn25245.1.31-36.fc27.5       @fedora
...
Available Packages
texlive-12many.noarch                    6:svn15878.0.3-36.fc27.5        fedora 
texlive-12many-doc.noarch                6:svn15878.0.3-36.fc27.5        fedora 
texlive-2up.noarch                       6:svn40417-36.fc27.5            fedora 
texlive-2up-doc.noarch                   6:svn40417-36.fc27.5            fedora 
texlive-ESIEEcv.noarch                   6:svn15878.0-36.fc27.5          fedora 
texlive-ESIEEcv-doc.noarch               6:svn15878.0-36.fc27.5          fedora 
texlive-FAQ-en-doc.noarch                6:svn34303.3.28-36.fc27.5       fedora 
...
```

The result has three columns: the package name, the version and the repository. Then `dnf` groups the list into two parts: *installed* and *available*. If we want to look only for available packages, we simply add the `available` modifier to the command:

```
$ dnf list available texlive-*
```

Similarly, by adding `installed` does the exact opposite: it shows the installed packages matching the string query.

Of course, this list might not be as useful as one might thinks. Let us try something different. Suppose that I want to use the `datatool` package. Packages, as we know, have the `.sty` extension, so we need to look for a file named `datatool.sty`. We can issue `dnf` again:

```
$ dnf provides */datatool.sty
Last metadata expiration check: 0:49:45 ago on Fri Dec 22 09:17:10 2017.
texlive-datatool-6:svn39421-36.fc27.5.noarch : Tools to load and manipulate data
Repo        : fedora
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool.sty
```

Observe the `*/datatool.sty` query. If you look only for `datatool.sty`, `dnf` will try to find a package that matches that name *and* path. Since this file surely won't be in the root of a filesystem, the match will yield no results. As the name implies, `dnf provides` will look for packages that provide the file entered in the query. And we found out the file is in `texlive-datatool`.

It is important to note that `dnf` will only look for files in your *enabled* repositories. I know this might sound obvious, but it's good for you to know that. `:)`

Now, let's try a different approach. There's a strange package named `texlive-carlisle`, I wonder what it is! Let us list the contents of such package:

```
$ dnf repoquery -l texlive-carlisle
Last metadata expiration check: 0:55:05 ago on Fri Dec 22 09:17:10 2017.
/usr/share/licenses/texlive-carlisle
/usr/share/licenses/texlive-carlisle/lppl1.txt
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/dotlessj.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/ltxtable.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/mylatex.ltx
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/plain.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/remreset.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/scalefnt.sty
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/slashed.sty
```

Bear in mind that the package does not need to be installed in your system, you can list the contents of any package, installed or available.

And that's it. `:)`

Comment: Nice. Does searching for filenames work for available (not installed) packages? This was the main problem, when searching with zypper. I'm asking because `dnf` is also available for SuSE but it seems to find only installed files.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Yes, it seems so. I tried with `datatool.sty` in my laptop and it gave me `texlive-datatool`, which was not installed. Which version of `dnf` does SuSE have?

Comment: dnf-2.7.5 if the repo-info is correct (I've removed it, because it did not do what I want).

Comment: @Schweinebacke same version as mine. Interesting, perhaps there might be some hidden settings...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: you naughty German! `:)`

Comment: I added an extra answer for Fedora, please feel free to incorporate it into your answer so all the information is in one place.

Answer (score 12):

[image: arch linux logo]

Arch has two ways for doing this (well, two ways of which I'm aware, anyway):

- With the package manager (`pacman`),
- and with an add-on tool called `pkgfile`.

---

### Pacman

First, update the database for files which are in packages which you do not have installed on your system (now there's a mouthful), which you can then query with the `-F` option:

`sudo pacman -Fy`

Then you can query the database like so (for texmaker, as an example):

```
$ pacman -Fo /usr/bin/texmaker
usr/bin/texmaker is owned by community/texmaker 5.0.2-1
```

The problem here is that you need to know the actual path of the file. Not much use if you're looking for a (La)TeX package (at least not to me -- I certainly don't know my texmf-dist tree by heart). But still, the option exists.

More geared towards our use case is the `s` option though, which allows searching for a filename (note that the query for `datatool.sty` will yield an empty result if you run it with `pacman -Fo`):

```
$ pacman -Fs datatool.sty
extra/texlive-latexextra 2017.45733-1
    usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool.sty
```

<s>According to the manpages, this search mechanism *should* also support regexes,  but I have not found a way to get them to work. So if I want to do wildcard searches, so far I need to use another way.</s>

Thanks to Fox for the hint about the `-x` option; I'd overlooked that when browsing the manpages:

```
$ pacman -Fxs 'data.*\.sty'
```

This will give you a list of packages and the files within those packages which match the regex:

```
extra/texlive-latexextra 2017.45733-1
    usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/dataref/dataref.sty
    usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/databar.sty
    usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/databib.sty
    usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datagidx.sty
    [ etc. ]
```

---

### pkgfile

First, install as usual:

```
sudo pacman -S pkgfile
sudo pgkfile --update
```

The default works pretty much like one would expect:

```
$ pkgfile datatool.sty
extra/texlive-latexextra
```

But let's say we want to find all packages which own a file with `tikz` in it, case-insensitive, via regular expression syntax:

```
$ pkgfile -ri '.*tikz.*'
extra/gnuplot
extra/rocs
extra/texlive-core
extra/texlive-latexextra
extra/texlive-pictures
extra/texlive-science
community/auctex
community/gap-packages
community/polymake
community/sagemath-doc
```

You could then query those packages if you wanted to get the specific files. For `auctex`, as an example:

```
$ pkgfile -l auctex|grep -i tikz
community/auctex        /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/auctex/style/tikz.el
community/auctex        /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/auctex/style/tikz.elc
```

And the same query can also be run with pacman (though, funnily enough, it's actually slower than pkgfile, at least on my machine):

```
$ pacman -Fl auctex | grep -i tikz
auctex usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/auctex/style/tikz.el
auctex usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/auctex/style/tikz.elc
```

---

### Arch Wiki

The Arch wiki also has [a page on TeX Live](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TeX_Live), which is probably worth a look. Basically, you have the following package groups:

- `texlive-most` : includes most TeX Live applications
- `texlive-lang` : provides various character sets and non-English features

Note that `texlive-core` is based on the *medium* install scheme of TeX Live.

I usually just install `texlive-most` and `texlive-lang` on my machines. I have almost never had an issue with a missing package. Downside is that it's not exactly a lightweight affair.

(**EDIT:** cleaned up some confusing terminology stemming from the difference between packages and package groups.)

---

**EDIT**:
See also [this answer on the Unix/Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14865)

Comment: I want to try Arch some day! `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda it is a good way to avoid your thesis ;)

Comment: @StrongBad: oh no, I've been spotted. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda I've been using it as my daily driver since 2011, and while I wouldn't say it's perfect by any means, it has served me very well since then on desktops, laptops and servers. And it's honestly not as hard as people tend to say (then again, maybe that's just my experience skewing my perspective). ;-)

Comment: I don't like this at all. I can't help feeling that `-y` thing is really nasty. Surely all sane people use `pkgfile`? There's also at least `texlive-latexextra` and probably some more. Personally, I don't think it is KISS to use Arch's packages for TL. ;)

Comment: Note that `sudo` is not installed by default. Your answer assumes it is available.

Comment: @crf pacman If I'm not misinterpreting the manpages, the files database (`-F`) is different than the sync and local databases.,  If you've never run `pacman -Fy`, it will be empty at first. It doesn't interfere with system upgrades, the `-y` is just to populate it. And yes, you could of course run this without sudo if you're logged in as root or another user with sufficient privileges. And yeah, I seem to have mixed up some package groups and packages, I shall edit my answer to fix that. Thanks for the hint! And... do sane people run Arch at all. ;-)

Comment: @Fox Ah, splendid, thanks! I will amend my post.

Answer (score 3):

For recent Fedora, you can, e.g.

```
$ dnf install 'tex(datatool.sty)'
```

if you happen to know the filename. It seems quite slow on my admittedly aging hardware though.

Answer (score 0):

With Debian, I use aptitude, as it allows me to see which packages I have installed, and a description of them, through the Ncurses interface, but:

If you access aptitude on the command-line, and request `install (packagename)', even if it isn't available in that form, aptitude will come back with the message,`there is no package of that description, but it is mentioned in the package description of `texlive-such&such'-for example, which you can then go ahead and install, gaining the function you need.

Other posters are correct.
If you're going to ask a question, provide a greater degree of information.
For all anybody here knows, you could be using Redhat, Suse, Debian, Gentoo, or any of the distributions built off them, all of which have different package managers, and different modes of dealing with the issue.