Compilation problems right after updating to Ubuntu 24.04 [can't find supp-pdf]
let me start with a comment that I'm not an expert and I really don't understand things concerning LaTeX very well. Thus I apologize in advance if the question is vague and imprecise.
Recently, I have updated my system to Ubuntu 24.04 (I guess from the last version). Right after that, the problem appeared: it concerns compiling my .tex files which have references to the .mp files, I guess through the MPost macro I am using (I don't know how this exactly  works, since I obtained the prepared macro file from my friend, so the instructions how to use it - if necessary I'll provide more details). The thing is, that before the update, everything was perfectly working; now, after compilation I receive the following message
! I can't find file `supp-pdf'.<to be read again>\scan_stop:

This message refers to the following line in the aforementioned MPost macro:
\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined\input epsf \else\input supp-pdf\fi 

(if needed, I may attach more from this file). Do you have any idea why such problem appeared right after the update and, more importantly, how to fix it? Let me add, that the compilation works perfectly, when there is no reference to .mp files.
My thoughts and attempts to solve the problem
As far as I can remember, during the Ubuntu update I was questioned if I would like to remove some packages considered to be unnecessary or something like that. I remember I decided to remove them and I guessed that might be the reason of my problem. Therefore I purged Texlive using these instructions: How to remove everything related to TeX Live for fresh install on Ubuntu? and I reinstalled the full version of it, using apt-get. Unfortunately, it didn't work - the problem stayed the same. Then I've decided to check if the "lost" 'supp-pdf' file is there:
$ locate supp-pdf
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/accsupp/accsupp-pdftex.def

and it turned out it is. I assume it is in the right place, so why the problem appears?
Tex version I'm using is TeX 3.141592653 (TeX Live 2023/Debian). Every single piece of advise will be appreciated, thank you in advance.
The full code
Here is the full MPost macro code that I use:
\catcode`@=11
\def\@input#1{\openin\ind@@ks #1 \ifeof\ind@@ks 
  \immediate\write16{No file #1.}\else\closein\ind@@ks\relax\input #1 \fi}

\def\newlabelwp#1#2{\@ifundefined{r@#1}{}%
   {\immediate\write16{OSTRZEZENIE: Odnosnik #1 juz istnieje...}}
   \expandafter\def\csname r@#1\endcsname{#2}}

\long\def\@ifundefined#1#2#3{\expandafter\ifx\csname
  #1\endcsname\relax#2\else#3\fi}

\newread\ind@@ks  \@input{\jobname.bux}
\newwrite\ind@ks \immediate\openout\ind@ks=\jobname.bux

\def\labelwp#1#2{\immediate\write\ind@ks{\noexpand\newlabelwp{#1}{#2}}}

\def\refwp#1{\@ifundefined{r@#1}%
{\immediate\write16{OTRZEZENIE: Odnosnik #1 nie istnieje. PrzeTeXuj
jeszcze raz...}{\bf ??}}{\csname r@#1\endcsname}}

\catcode`@=12
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% koniec odnosnikow %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%



%% ladujemy pliki wsadowe do rysunkow:

\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined\input epsf \else\input supp-pdf\fi 

%% ladujemy makra do rysunkow i przypisania

\newcount\rysuncio
\newbox\rysunek
\newread\piczek

\def\includerys#1{\openin\piczek=#1
\ifeof\piczek\immediate\write16{OSTRZEZENIE: Nie ma pliku #1 z rysunkiem!}
\else
  \global\advance\rysuncio by1
  \labelwp{#1}{\the\rysuncio}
  \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
  \global\setbox\rysunek=\hbox{\epsfbox{#1}}
    \else
  \global\setbox\rysunek=\hbox{\convertMPtoPDF{#1}{1}{1}} 
  \fi
  \vbox{\copy\rysunek
    \hbox to\wd\rysunek{\vbox to13pt{}\footrm\hfil Rys.~\refwp{#1}\hfil}}
\fi\closein\piczek}

\def\includerysbok#1{\openin\piczek=#1
\ifeof\piczek\immediate\write16{OSTRZEZENIE: Nie ma pliku #1 z rysunkiem!}
\else
  \global\advance\rysuncio by1
   \labelwp{#1}{\the\rysuncio}
   \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
     \global\setbox\rysunek=\hbox{\epsfbox{#1}}
     \else
     \global\setbox\rysunek=\hbox{\convertMPtoPDF{#1}{1}{1}} 
  \fi
    \hbox to6truecm{\copy\rysunek \hfil\hbox{\small\rm rys.~\refwp{#1}}}
\fi\closein\piczek}

\def\includeryswp#1{\openin\piczek=#1
\ifeof\piczek\immediate\write16{OSTRZEZENIE: Nie ma pliku #1 z rysunkiem!}
\else
 \ifx\pdfoutput\undefined
  \global\setbox\rysunek=\hbox{\epsfbox{#1}}
    \else
  \global\setbox\rysunek=\hbox{\convertMPtoPDF{#1}{1}{1}} 
  \fi
 \vbox{\copy\rysunek}
\fi\closein\piczek}

%% makra do zakladek w pdf-ach:

\def\pdfbookmark#1#2#3{\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined\else
  \pdfoutline goto name{#1} count #3 {#2}\fi}

\def\pdfref#1#2{\ifx\pdfoutput\undefined\else
  \pdfdest name{#1} #2\fi}

I named this file figures-macros-wp.tex. And here is an example.tex file (without preamble):
\begin{document}

\input figures-macros-wp.tex

\centerline{\includerys{example.1}}

\end{document}

where example.mp is any MPost file (all files: figures-macros-wp.tex, example.mp and example.tex should be in one folder).

welcome! can you provide the code for a minimal example which produces the problem so we can test?

but locate supp-pdf should find a third file with a .tex extension.

you should have e.g. /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.tex, so you need to find out which ubuntu or debian package provides that file and to install that package. texlive-full is not usually the full version of texlive, though I've not checked debian's packaging in particular.

@DavidCarlisle that location is wrong and so is the version.

@cfr thank you for information, I even came up with that I might not possess a full version of texlive (as I mentioned, I installed texlive-full through apt). Do you know precisely how can I find the missing package?

Try apt-file https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407277/106162 to locate which Ubuntu package you need

I used it and I got the following
$ sudo apt-file search supp-pdf
texlive-latex-base: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
texlive-latex-extra: /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/accsupp/accsupp-pdftex.def
So there's no supp-pdf.tex and both of the above packages are already installed

@Karol66 it could be a bug in the Ubuntu package, where they forgot this particular file. In that case it would be best to file a bug report in Launchpad. However, maybe it is just set up in a different way, it would be good if you can post a short example file that generates the error that you get. If you do file a bug with Ubuntu then such a minimal file would also be necessary.

I edited the question, so that it should be possible to test and verify, at least I hope so

I'm not a ConTeXt or MetaPost expert by any means but the code you provided seems very low-level and maybe not needed - what is the goal of running this code exactly? I have the same install as you I think (apt install texlive-full on Ubuntu 24.04) which does not have supp-pdf.tex but I can compile MetaPost figures within ConTeXt with pdf output without any problems when I just use \startMPcode and \stopMPcode, either with \input myfigure.mp within this environment or by adding the drawing commands directly without \input.

@Marijn I think the OP is using this in latex. it isn't entirely clear as we still don't have a complete example, but the document environment certainly looks like latex.

try adding supp-pdf.tex to your working directory with the following content: \input supp-pdf.mkii. if that works, report as a bug to ubuntu or debian (whoever packages this for ubuntu). there should be a couple of .tex files in that directory. context users don't need them, but non-context users do. so, if they've been removed because unneeded by context, another package should be created to provide them. but you'll need a complete and minimal example to stand a good chance of getting the bug fixed. (depends on packager, but generally.) 4 files with 1 doing-who-knows-what won't cut it.
